# our readers thought that

Tags: meaning, articles, possessives

> a. When that article was published, readers thought that the policy of our journal had changed.

> b. When that article was published, the readers thought that the policy of our journal had changed.

> c. When that article was published, our readers thought that the policy of our journal had changed.

What are the differences in the meanings?

I think 'the readers' refers to all those you read the article, and 'our readers' refers to all of the readers of the magazine. I might be wrong.

I suppose 'readers' could mean 'some readers', but I am not sure that implication is there. Maybe it means 'some or all readers' or maybe it is just shorthand for 'our readers'?

How would you interpret the sentences?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any particular difference in meaning, just a stylistic choice.

*Readers* is just a conventional way of saying 'people who had read the article'.